# Unit tests stops half way when adding certain assertions

Tags: ruby, unit-testing

I am trying to write some unit testing for my ruby script. However, it is not working as I think it should work, and with certain tests, it just stops half way through the unit test.

This is the method I am currently testing.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'ptools'
require 'test/unit'

class InputValidators
    # checks whether the input file exist.
    def input_file_validator(input_file)
        begin
            raise ArgumentError, "Error: Input file \"#{input_file}\" does not exist. \n" unless File.exist?(input_file)
            raise ArgumentError, "Error: Input file is empty. Please correct this and try again. \n" if File.zero?(input_file)
            raise ArgumentError, "Error: Input file is in binary format - only text based input files are supported. \n" if File.binary?(input_file)
        rescue Exception => e
            puts # a empty line
            puts e.message
            puts # a empty line
            Process.exit(true)
        end
    end
end

class UnitTests < Test::Unit::TestCase
    def test_input_file_validator_1
        test_validators = InputValidators.new
            assert_equal(nil, test_validators.input_file_validator("./test_inputs/genetic.fna")) #file is present
            assert_raise( SystemExit ) {test_validators.input_file_validator("./test_inputs/missing_input.fna")} # file doesn't exist
#           assert_equal(nil, test_validators.input_file_validator("./test_inputs/empty_file.fna")) # empty file
#           assert_equal(nil, test_validators.input_file_validator("./test_inputs/binary_file.fna")) # a binary file
    end
end
```

Now, if I leave the script as above, the unit test work perfectly...

Current Output:

```
Run options: 

# Running tests:

[1/1] UnitTests#test_input_file_validator_1

Error: Input file "./test_inputs/missing_input.fna" does not exist. 

Finished tests in 0.004222s, 236.8797 tests/s, 473.7593 assertions/s.
1 tests, 2 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips

ruby -v: ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-linux]
```

However, if I even uncomment one of the other asserts, the unit test just stops and doesn't complete.

Output (when uncommenting just one or both of the assertions in the above script):

```
Run options: 

# Running tests:

[1/1] UnitTests#test_input_file_validator_1
Error: Input file "./test_inputs/missing_input.fna" does not exist. 


Error: Input file is empty. Please correct this and try again.
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong so any help on this would be most appreciated.
Let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, if you run `exit` and you are not rescuing from that exception, your process just stops running.

i guess that `assert_raise` does actually capture that error or does some other magic to complete the process. running `at_exit` hooks might be some of those magic tricks.

despite all this, it's considered a bad practice to use exceptions for workflows. so i would not recommend raising an error and then catching it immediately just to exit the process. i usually just use `abort` with a message.

Comment: Thanks, this is my first time using ArgumentErrors, So do you suggest raising an Argument Error at all or should I somehow raise the argument error and then abort or should I just make the condition and the abort statement.

Comment: raise the error and handle it elsewhere if you want to test it. i would not even bother and just have the check in my script as it wont function anyways if the file does not exist